# Unrecognized %option bison-bridge with flex 2.5.4

Tags: windows, mingw, bison, flex-lexer

I've just installed flex and I'm trying some simple tests with its 2.5.4 version on windows 7 64bits.
I'd like to integrate it with a bison generated parser.
Therefore, the [flex manual](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~akim/ccmp/doc/flex-2.5.22.html#Scanner%20Options) says that one must declare %option bison-bridge.

When running flex on the input .l file, I get an error:

```
Unrecognized %option bison-bridge
```

I tried to set this option in the command line rather than in the input, but when typing:

```
flex.exe --help
```

No available option sets a "bison-bridge"...

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using such an ancient version of [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex)?  Version 2.5.31 was released in 2003; the current version is 2.5.37 from August 2012.

I'm not sure when Flex 2.5.4 was released (the source is still available at the URL above), but it probably simply does not include the functionality you're after.

Upgrade!

Comment: I'm on windows and it's the only build I found to install it !

Comment: Can you tell me how to install newest version of flex on windows ?

Comment: Do you have Cygwin or something similar?  If so, you should be able to get a modern Flex (perhaps 2.5.35 from April 2012, or otherwise 2.5.34 from 2008).  You should check when the `bison-bridge` option was added; I don't recall seeing it before, but I've certainly not scrutinized the manual in each release or pushed Flex to its limits.  Where did you get a version of Bison that uses the `bison-bridge` option?  Can you find an appropriate Flex there too?

Comment: Yeah I've been installing cygwin since you last replied and I've made it install flex 2.5.37 and latest bison with dependencies. Thank you very much.
About the %option bison-bridge, it's in the manual ! It makes the generated scanner use the global variable yylvalue in order to pass the value associated with the last seen token to the bison-generated parser...

Comment: You should be good to go once Cygwin is ready.  Thanks for the info on the option.

Comment: Yep ! I confirm that it works just fine now thru cygwin ! thanks again Jonathan ! (If I can call you Jonathan ^^)

Answer (score 4):

Well, using a more recent version of flex is the best answer, but if you really MUST use an older version of flex, this kind of functionality used to be accessible by defining the `YY_DECL` macro in the top of the .l file:

```
%{
#define YY_DECL    int yylex(YYSTYPE *yylval)
%}
```

would do the equivalent of `%option bison-bridge`

Answer (score 2):

you can use latest versions of flex&bison for windows from http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/